# Is denying the .env file via htaccess enough for laravel application security?

Tags: php, laravel, security

In shared hosting, I installed all laravel application files in the root folder (public_html). But also I deny the .env file via htaccess.

1. **So is denying the .env file via htaccess enough for application security?**
2. **Do I have to install the app at the same directory level of public_html and do i have to create a symlink?**

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deploy Laravel app on shared hosting properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72242998/deploy-laravel-app-on-shared-hosting-properly)

Comment: No, the link mentions proper way to install laravel app. But what I wonder is 1st question's answer.

Comment: If your shared hosting have no possibility to target public directory and you have no access to your www parent user directory (`/home/user/public_html`) then I would seriously consider switching hosting provider. There are usually one of 2 options available: 1) in your hosting you can target your site public directory, in this case it would be `public_html/public` or 2) move your laravel app in parent directory and change path for your `index.php`, in this case `public_html/index.php`.

Comment: @KristapsJ. thanks. I am able to install my laravel app properly. But, I wonder, if I install the app public_html folder and If I deny the requests for .env file. Is that OK for security. You know .env file contains sensitive data.

Comment: no. you must design your application itself securely as well.

Comment: No, it's not enough for security. You might have sensitive information in the `storage` folder (logs, for example), or you might misconfigure PHP and have your entire source code revealed as plain text. The proper setup prevents these from being an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So is denying the .env file via htaccess enough for application security?

No.

Examples of where this would not be sufficient:

- Someone could access files like `storage/logs/laravel.log` and see potentially sensitive information.
- Misconfiguring/breaking PHP on the server would permit users to browse your PHP files as plain text, potentially revealing the entirety of your source code.